# How do we find the critical point using partial derivatives?

Tags: calculus

If $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}= 0$ when $x = 1$, and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = (2y-x)$

Do we have to replace $x$ by 1? to get the critical coordinate $y$?

Comment: Indeed you have :)

Answer (score 1):

The critical points occur when $f_{x}=f_{y}=0$.  So, necessarily, any critical point must occur when $x=1$ so that we obtain $2y-1=0$ and $y=\frac{1}{2}$ as desired.  So you are correct.

Comment: Note that just because $(1, \frac{1}{2})$ is a potential critical point doesn't mean it *is* one--you still need to check $f_y$

Comment: @anorton No, the definition of a critical point is that the partial derivatives are zero.  However, just because it is a critical point does not mean that it is a maximum or minimum, which might be what you are referring to.

Comment: I disagree...  My textbook ("University Calculus" by Hass, Weir, and Thomas) defines a critical point as "An interior point of the domain of a function $f(x,y)$ where both $f_x$ and $f_y$ are zero or where one or both of $f_x$ and $f_y$ do not exist is a **critical point** of $f$."  Wikipedia also verifies this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_%28mathematics%29#Several_variables

Comment: @anorton That's what I'm saying.  That's not what you said.  I don't know what you mean by a "potential critical point."

Comment: Oh.  Sorry.  I meant it has the _potential_ to be a critical point.  It could be, but we don't know yet.  To verify, we must know $f_y$.